# OnMouseOver event triggered by non existing elements with ID = blank and ID = undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a menu that appears when the user hovers on an icon. I would like it to close when the user hovers out of that menu, or its parent DIV. In order to do that, I thought of using the onMouseOver and hiding it when the ID is not one of those I want. However, when I move the mouse, the cursor seems to enter and exit elements I didn't put there myself, with undefined ID or ID = '' (  blank ). Can anybody explain what is causing it, and, possibly, how to stop that from happening?

This is the menu, with its elements

```
<div class = "desktopToolbarSearchBoxWithoutOptions" id = "toolbarSearchBox">
    <img src = "${webAppRoot}images/sandwich.png" class = "menuSearchSelector pointer" onMouseOver = "showSearchOptions ()" id = "menuSearchSelector"/>

    <span class="toolbarMenuItem pointer" id = "option1">
        Subject
    </span>

    <span class="toolbarMenuItem pointer" id = "option2">
        Name
    </span>

    <span class="toolbarMenuItem pointer" id = "option3">
        Location
    </span>
</div>
```

This is how I make all the elements respond to the onmouseover event. I have to admit that I am more of a server person and can't make any sense of that for loop expression, I copied it from another forum where it said it does what I need. Maybe that's where the problem lies?

```
function startClickListener() 
{
    document.addEventListener
    (
        "mouseover", function ( e ) 
        {
            for ( var element = e.target; element; element = element.parentNode ) 
            {
                console.log ( "> > > Element ID : " + element.id );
            }
        }
    );
}
```

I would like the menu to disappear every time the ID is not one of those I want. However, even when moving between option1, option2 and option3 span I get those ghost elements

```
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
( 2 x ) 8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : menuSearchSelector
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
( 2 x ) 8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
( 2 x ) 8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : option1
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
( 2 x ) 8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : option2
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
( 2 x ) 8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:688 > > > Element ID : option3
```

Then I thought I could use the ID of the parentNode, as long as it's an element inside the DIV with ID = 'toolbarSearchBox', I am happy. It seems that those ghost elements do not even belong to that DIV though. Maybe the error message I get is a clue?

```
function startClickListener() 
{
    document.addEventListener
    (
        "mouseover", function ( e ) 
        {
            for ( var element = e.target; element; element = element.parentNode ) 
            {
                console.log ( "> > > Element ID : " + element.id );
                console.log ( "> > > Parent  ID : " + element.parentNode.id );
            }
        }
    );
}
```

This is the outcome

```
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:687 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (8BM_js.jsp:687) (anonymous) @ 8BM_js.jsp:687
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : menuSearchSelector
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:687 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (8BM_js.jsp:687) (anonymous) @ 8BM_js.jsp:687
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:687 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (8BM_js.jsp:687) (anonymous) @ 8BM_js.jsp:687
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : option1
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:687 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (8BM_js.jsp:687) (anonymous) @ 8BM_js.jsp:687
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : option2
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:687 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (8BM_js.jsp:687) (anonymous) @ 8BM_js.jsp:687
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : option3
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : toolbarSearchBox
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : desktopToolbar
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : 
8BM_js.jsp:687 > > > Parent  ID : undefined
8BM_js.jsp:686 > > > Element ID : undefined
```

Comment: you could add the eventlistener to the icon that shows the options, no? or is this more a general question regarding the empty ID elements?

Comment: @rebecca The icon correctly opens the menu with the options. I would like to intercept the mouse over or mouse out for every element, so that when the mouse leaves the DIV with the options, they disappear. For example: if ID of element mouse is over is not "option1", "option2" or "option3" then close the option div. But when going from an option to the other, it also enters those ghost elements with ID = '' or = undefined, which I don't know how end up there...

Comment: I'd assume those are your body or html tags maybe? if you add an id to your `body` and `html` tag, are you still getting empty id's?

Comment: @rebecca I never knew HTML and BODY tags could have IDs! Now they do appear in the console, so that has solved part of the problem... Still have a few undefined or blank IDs, but I will just make sure everything in the page has one now! Thanks so much :-) Definitely a hint I would have never worked out myself

Comment: mmh i think instead of adding id's to all of your elements you should rethink how you're tackling the problem. for example: you could check if the `e.target` has the right class of your icon and if so, show the options, if not, hide the options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut events are triggered by children of the elements too, and sometimes by other elements too - couldn't quite understand when and why. OnMouseLeave doesn't have the same problem and is only triggered when the mouse leaves the element it's attached to